# Cannot Copy MS Word Controls

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

As the title states - I'm trying to copy controls (a combo box) from one MS Word (2010, .docx) file to another but no matter whether I use design mode or not, it just pastes as text into the other document rather than as a control.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you please attach a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: I'm not sure a screenshot would help, as it looks correct - it's meant to be a combo box that _looks_ like text but allows the user to select a value (it's for a document template). Unfortunately, when I try and copy it to other document templates it just copies as a piece of text rather than as a control.